# Installing LibHX on Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, shared-libraries

1. I have installed LibHX using the Synaptic Packet Manager.
2. I can see the libHX.so.22 file in /usr/lib
   3 I have run ldconfig -n /usr/lib

How do I go ahead and use this library in my C files? 
any attempt to run this command yields in error:

```
gcc -L /usr/lib/libHX.so.22 V1.c
```

results in error V1.c Line3: No such file or directory. Compilation terminated

I can't figure out how to go forward.
Would appreciate some help

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and gcc 4.4.5

Comment: A step by step instruction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install the development package for libhx, it is probably called libhx-dev . Libraries usually come in 2 packages, one for the run time support that includes the compiled shared library, and one for development that includes header files, often a static library, and other things.
- Read the libhx [documentation](http://libhx.sf.net/).
- #include the header files you need in your code
- Compile your source code

  gcc -Wall -c myfile.c
- link your files to produce the program, and link to the libhx library

  gcc -o myprogram -lHX myfile.o

Now - the libhx development uses [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/) . This means you can run pkg-config to learn which compiler flags you need to use for compiling a program using libhx and which flags to use when linking your program.

Run e.g. `pkg-config --cflags libHX` and `pkg-config --libs libHX` to see which flags you should use. This means you can compile/link your program using something like:

```
 gcc -Wall -c $(pkg-config --cflags libHX) myfile.c 
 gcc -o myprogram $(pkg-config --libs libHX) myfile.o
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply. I am sorry to ask you a question even on this, what is myprogram here? I am assuming that I have written my source code in myfile.c

Comment: Its the name of the output, gcc links myfile.o and the required libraries, and produces the executable `myprogram` , which you can run

Comment: When I run `gcc -o myprogram -lhx myfile.o` I get this error message, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhx`

Comment: @Soham Seems the library is named libHX , so use -lHX (capital HX) - assuming you have installed libhx-dev.

Comment: Yes that works. Thank you so much, nos. I really learned a lot from this interaction. Is it generic(the format) for all other kinds of libraries in C?